# How to prevent grunt from live reloading multiple times when multiple files are updated?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a grunt watch task with multiple sub-tasks for watching LESS, CoffeeScript, etc.

```
    watch:
        jade:
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/*.jade']
            tasks: ['jade']
        less:
            files: ['<%= yeoman.css %>/*.less']
            tasks: ['less']
        coffee:
            files: ['<%= yeoman.scripts %>/*.coffee']
            tasks: ['coffee']
        edge:
            files: ['<%= yeoman.comp %>/*']
            tasks: ['edge']
        livereload:
            options:
                livereload: true
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html'
                '<%= yeoman.css %>/*.css'
                '<%= yeoman.scripts %>/*.js'
            ]
```

I also have a custom task I wrote that's responsible for processing a set of 3rd party files that get updated frequently. Task updates several paths within the 3rd party javascript and html files and then redistributes them to appropriate locations within the main project.

The problem is when each of these files is written to their destination, the related grunt task is run each one triggers a live reload. So if 4 files are written, 4 separate reloads occur.

Is there any way to configure the watch task to consolidate all live reloading events into a single reload at the "end"?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out personally, but you may find [tiny-lr](https://github.com/mklabs/tiny-lr#using-grunt) worth looking into. If you are writing a custom task then you can post a request to the tiny-lr server to reload multiple files at once (you could potentially do this via something like grunt-shell):

```
# notify a single change
curl http://localhost:35729/changed?files=style.css

# notify using a longer path
curl http://localhost:35729/changed?files=js/app.js

# notify multiple changes, comma or space delimited
curl http://localhost:35729/changed?files=index.html,style.css,docs/docco.css
```

I'm not sure if the standard config does what you require on its own, but its worth a shot:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('tiny-lr');
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    reload: {
      files: ['**/*.html', '**/*.js', '**/*.css', '**/*.{png,jpg}'],
      tasks: 'tinylr-reload'
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('reload', ['tinylr-start', 'watch']);
```

There's also [grunt-newer](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-newer) which only runs tasks based on the files that changed. I use this with my watch setup and it saves a lot of time, because it doesn't have to process every single file each time only one is saved.

Hope this helps.